# What should the result be of a failing parseInt function?

Tags: design, javascript, api-design

When providing JavaScript's `parseInt` with a non-parsable string it returns `NaN`. I'm trying to understand the reasons for designing a parsing function this way.

When I write a parsing function I usually return `null` or throw an exception in case the input is not parsable. It seems to me that `NaN` is unsafe because it allows the code to keep running even when there is no value to work with.

For example, this will not throw any runtime error:

```js
parseInt('a') + 1
```

But this could lead to unexpected behavior when you expect something to be an actual number while it's actually `NaN`. But perhaps there is a benefit to doing this that I'm not seeing.

**So my question is:** Are there significant dis-/advantages to the solutions below?

1. Returning `NaN`
2. Returning `null`
3. Throwing an exception
4. Something else

Comment: [Is asking “why” on language specs still considered as “primary opinion-based” if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/839601)

Comment: This is JavaScript.  You were [expecting it to make sense](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)?

Comment: Also, why would checking for NaN be any different than checking for null?

Comment: @gnat Thanks for the feedback, I've edited my question clarify that I'm not actually looking to understand why JS does this. I just want to know why **I** should do it (or not). Please consider removing the downvote or explain how I can improve the question further

Comment: Are you writing your parsing function in JavaScript or some other language? If you're writing it in JavaScript, I think a case can be made for being consistent with the way JavaScript does things.  For any other language, I think you've made a better case for returning `null`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm actually using TypeScript myself, which doesn't allow adding `null` to a `number`. I assumed that JS would be the same, but apparently that's not the case. Although in JS there is still a difference between adding a number to `null` instead `NaN` so someone could argue that one is better than the other.

Comment: I think you clearly understand the tradeoffs already.  What do *you* want to do?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Like I mentioned in my question I'm just looking to understand why `NaN` should be used (or not) in order to improve my own API design skills/knowledge. I'm wondering if there is any benefit to use one solution over the other that I am not aware of.

Comment: You already know that.  `NaN` has the potential for unforseen and subtle bugs, while `null` is a well-known and well-understood response to a parsing failure.

Comment: And if you're wondering if there's any rationale behind the decision to use `NaN` in JavaScript, I assume it's because the result of parsing non-numeric text is literally "Not a Number."

Comment: Design decisions made in the past don't have to make sense.  JavaScript was designed in ten days, 25 years ago.  It was intended to do small scripting things, but has since been co-opted to produce entire applications.  Compare that time frame with the design of Clojure, which Rich Hickey spent 18 months on.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So I guess your answer is that it's better to not use `NaN` in this case, and JS just designed it that way because they might not have thought it through well enough. Is that correct? And how about throwing an error, isn't that the actual solution here? I mean, if something isn't parsable, then it shouldn't evaluate to anything, right?

Comment: Honestly, I think you have to look at *your specific use case,* and decide which way makes the most sense in that context.  Thought experiment: how would you want this result to show up in a JSON object: `NaN`, `null`, or missing?

Comment: @RobertHarvey My use case is designing better interface for JavaScript's `parseInt` function. So what the result should be in a JSON object depends on the invoker's requirements, not mine.

Comment: I would argue that returning `null` and returning `NaN` are pretty much equivalent: both require the caller to check the result, and will result in errors of one sort or another if they don't. There may be differences in how convenient the language / context makes that check, but they're fundamentally both saying "you asked for an integer, but I can't give you one, so I'm going to give you something else instead".

Comment: @IMSoP: I think there is a difference, in that while `NaN` is "not a number", it *is* a `number` (and implicitly coercible to `Number`), meaning it supports all arithmetic operators and all methods of `Number`. So, while `null + 42` will give an error, `NaN + 42` won't.

Comment: @JörgWMittag It's a good point that `NaN` is actually a `number`, I also mention it in my answer. However, it's important to note that `null + 42` will actually **not** give an error, making it even more prone to bugs.

Comment: @DuncanLuk: You're right. Even if I take into account *how crazy* ECMAScript is, I still underestimate *how crazy* ECMAScript is. I still remember how shocked I was when I learned that equality of arrays is based on coercing the arrays to strings, or when I learned that `[2, 10].sort()` is `[10, 2]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Parsing functions are a complex beast, because they must be *designed to fail*. There are typically *at least as many* invalid inputs as there are valid ones. (E.g. for `parseInt` there are countably infinite valid inputs and countably infinite invalid inputs.)

Some common approaches to deal with this problem are:

## Return an optional type

Many languages / standard libraries have a type that represents the concept of "a value that may or may not be there" (or "zero or one of some thing"). This is typically called an `Option` or `Maybe` type. You can also think of it as a collection of length "at most one".

In fact, an `Option` type is isomorphic to a collection with at most one element, which means that it can implement all the collection APIs and thus be used like any other collection.

Here is an example from the Scala standard library: [`scala.collection.StringOps.toIntOption`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/StringOps.html#toIntOption:Option%5BInt%5D) returns an `Option[Int]`. So, for example

```scala
"10".toIntOption
//=> Some(10)

"foo".toIntOption
//=> None
```

This is personally my favorite. `Option` types have some really nice properties: they are not only monads, they are also collections. Collection operations are some of the most important operations in programming, so it is likely you are already proficient in them, and you can apply everything you know to `Option`s as well.

For example, you want to execute a side-effect with the value if it exists (e.g. print it)? Well, just iterate over the "collection": if it is empty, nothing will happen, and if the value exists, the body of the iteration will be executed exactly once.

So, instead of

```ecmascript
const i = parseInt("hello");

if (!isNan(i)) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

simply do

```ecmascript
for (const i of tryParse("hello")) console.log(i);
```

Want to transform it? Use `map`. Have a nested tower of `Option`s? `flat` it. And so on. If there is a `None` at any step of the calculation, it will just be propagated, but it will never fail. And you can ignore the "`Option`ness" most of the way, until you actually *need* the value. Then you need to extract it from the `Option` and decide what to do if it is not there.

Typically, there is a `getOrElse(default)` method that either returns the value or a default value of your choosing.

## Return an `Either` type

An `Either` type, as the name implies, is a parametric type constructor that represents the concept of "either this type or that type". It can be used for many different things, but it is often used to return either an intended result or a description of what went wrong.

An example is the [`Data.Text.Read.decimal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text/docs/Data-Text-Read.html#v:decimal) function in the Haskell `text` package.

When we look at the type of the `decimal` function and unpack it a little bit (and assume a concrete type for the `Integral a` type constraint), we can see that it basically has type

```haskell
decimal :: Text -> Either String (Int, Text)
```

So, it is a function that takes text as input and returns either a string (containing an error message) or a pair of an integer and the remaining text to be parsed.

If you aren't used to reading Haskell type signatures, this could by roughly translated into e.g. C# like this:

```csharp
Either<string, (int, string)> ParseDecimal(string text)
```

[Note that in the Haskell code, `String` is the traditional text type from the original Haskell specification, which is just a type alias for `[Char]`, i.e. a list of characters, whereas `Text` is a more modern encoding-aware type.]

## Return an `Error` type

An `Error` type is similar to an `Either` type in that it represents the concept of returning either one type or another type. But it is more constrained in two ways:

1. Only the "happy" type is a parameter, the other type is fixed to be some sort of type that represents an error. (Often a string with the error message, a pair with an error code and a message, or when retrofitted to a language with exceptions, an exception type).
2. The type is *biased* towards the "happy" type. This means that in many contexts, it can be treated like an `Option` of the "happy" type, whereas an `Either` typically always needs to be pattern matched or deconstructed, to check whether we are in the "left" or the "right" case.

So, an alternative to the above Haskell method could be:

```haskell
decimal :: Text -> Error (Int, Text)
```

This has the same advantages of a `Maybe` / `Option` type, except instead of just being informed that there is no value, you also get to know why.

## Throw an exception

This one is obvious: when the string does not contain a valid integer, you use the error handling facilities of the language. For example, that's what the [`Kernel#Integer`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) method does in Ruby:

```ruby
i = Integer("hello")
# invalid value for Integer(): "hello" (ArgumentError)
```

The main disadvantage is that this is kind of annoying: failing to parse an input is *not* an exceptional situation. It is completely normal. People make mistakes, typos. Files get corrupted. Your network daemon gets bombarded by junk from a previous connection that hasn't fully been cleaned up yet.

Exception handling is typically semantically and syntactically (and sometimes also pragmatically) heavyweight. That's a fair price to pay for an actual serious problem, but not for something that is completely normal.

## "Guard" the result with an additional success indicator

This is a term I just made up, so don't be surprised if you can't google it :-D

What I mean by that, is something like what .NET does with the `TryXXX` idiom: methods that might fail are named `TryXXX` and they return a `bool` that tells you whether the method was successful or not, and the *actual* return value is returned by reference in a reference parameter.

E.g. the type of [`int.TryParse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) is:

```csharp
bool TryParse(string s, out int result)
```

And it is used like this:

```csharp
int i;
if (TryParse("42"), i) {
    // do something with `i`
}
```

You can do the same thing by returning a tuple:

```csharp
(bool, int) TryParse(string s)

var (success, i) = TryParse("42"));
if (success) {
    // do something with `i`
}
```

Or in a language like Go that supports multiple return values:

```go
TryParse(string s) (int, bool)

if i, ok := TryParse("42"); ok {
    // do something with `i`
}
```

In Go, this is called the *"comma `ok`" idiom*, for obvious reasons.

Any language that has tuples, records, heterogeneous lists, objects, or really any kind of complex values supports (a variation of) this – instead of returning multiple values like in Go, you wrap the values into a light-weight data structure. E.g. in ECMAScript:

```ecmascript
function tryParse(s) {
    return { success: /* … */, result: /* … */ };
}

const { success, i } = tryParse("42");

if (success) {
    // do something with `i`
}

// or

function tryParse(s) {
    return [ /* … */, /* … */ ];
}

const [success, i] = tryParse("42");

if (success) {
    // do something with `i`
}
```

Personally, I very much prefer an `Option`, because then I can let the collections library deal with all the troubles. In particular, I can manipulate the value without ever having to check if it actually exists. I can leave that check and that decision to some other piece of code. Why should the computation code know how to deal with missing values? That's the User Interface's job!

## Return a *union type*

Some languages have a *union type* `A ∪ B`, i.e. a type whose set of values is the union of the sets its constituent types `A` and `B`.

For example in [Scala 3](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/union-types.html):

```scala
def tryParse(s: String): Int | false

val i = tryParse("42") match
  false => /* whatever value you want to use */
  Int(i) => i
```

I don't find this particularly good API design. That's not what union types are meant for. But it is a *possible* API design.

In a dynamically typed language, this is arguably more sensible. For example, in Ruby, the *only two* falsey values are `false` and `nil`, every other value is truthy, including all integers. In particular, unlike many other languages, `0` is truthy in Ruby. Therefore, something like this would actually make sense:

```ruby
def try_parse(s)
  return false if no_valid_integer?
  return i
end

i = try_parse("42")

if i
  # we know `i` is an integer and the parse was successful
end
```

## Return a "marker" value

In order to indicate failure, return a value that is a member of the return type, but not a possible value that can be parsed.

That is technically what ECMAScript's [`parseInt`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-parseint-string-radix) is doing. There is no integer type in ECMAScript, only the `number` type which is an IEEE 754-2019 binary64 double precision floating number. `NaN` is a valid `number` but it is not a valid integer, so by returning `NaN`, we can signal that the parse failed, but we are still returning a value of the same type.

## Return a default value

Another possibility is to return a default value if the parse fails. For example, in Ruby, conversion methods (`to_X`, `to_XYZ`) are not allowed to fail. Either you must *always* return a valid result, or you are simply not allowed to implement the method. the `to_X` methods are very lenient, the `to_XYZ` methods are very strict. So, for example, `String#to_int` does not exist, because it is not possible to always parse a string into an integer while also being strict about the value. [`String#to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-to_i) OTOH *does* exist, and it simply returns `0` when it cannot parse the string.

This has the big advantage that it *never* fails and always returns a valid result, but it has the big disadvantage that you have no way of knowing whether the string actually contained a valid integer or not.

## Return a `null` value

This is what you propose in your question with returning `null`.

In languages like ECMAScript, where `null` is coercible to almost anything, this can easily lead to hiding errors. For example, `null + 42 === 42`, whereas `NaN + 42 === NaN`. So, by returning `NaN`, we can *at least* tell that *somewhere, something* went wrong, even if we don't where, what, when, and why. But with `null`, it is just swallowed, in the end, you have no indication that it was even there.

## Return a `null` reference

These two often get confused. However, a `null` value is *still* a value. A reference to a `null` value can still be dereferenced. Dereferencing a `null` reference, however, will blow up in various ways. It might be a reasonably safe way as in Java, where it is guaranteed to throw a `NullPointerException`, or it might be completely unpredictable as in C.

Out of all the options, I personally find this the worst one.

Comment: “Null value” seems bad in JavaScript. In Swift, returning nil is absolutely fine - there is no way getting around checking for nil values right where they are returned.

Comment: Ruby would be similar. `nil` in Ruby would be pretty idiomatic, actually. It starts to break down for something like JSON or YAML parsing, where `nil` would actually be a valid value.

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no useful way to decide *within the parser function*.

Converting primitive types into each other is a sufficiently basic operation that it can be used in infinitely varied circumstances and purposes. You have no idea what the result be used for, how important it is, etc. Only the caller can know whether a conversion failure can be tolerated or not. Therefore the only thing you must do is pick a convention, document it clearly and stick to it.

Comment: In which scenario’s would failure be tolerated? I can’t imagine a use case where someone’s like “Well, the result is not a number but I’ll use it in my calculations anyway”

Comment: @DuncanLukkenaer: Such behavior would often be appropriate in interactive applications which continuously update a read-only text field to show the results of performing some computations on a user-editable field.  If the user enters a valid number, the field should show the correct result as soon as the input is valid and complete, whether or not the application knows it's complete.  If the user knows the field isn't complete, the user will know that the result isn't correct yet, and if the input is recognizably invalid, having the result show as NaN may be nicer than triggering a pop-up.

Comment: @DuncanLukkenaer: Such behavior may also be appropriate in many match-mode operations which should process records independently, and receive a mixture of valid and invalid ones.  Indicating that parts of the output can't be meaningfully computed would be better than having the presence of some invalid records prevent any useful output from being produced.

Answer (score 0):

After the discussions in the comments I'm able to answer my own question.

#### Returning `NaN`

This isn't recommended because this can lead to unforseen and subtle bugs due to JavaScript allowing operations like `NaN + 1`.

The reason it's designed this way in JavaScript is likely because it wasn't fully thought through.

Quoting @RobertHarvey:

> JavaScript was designed in ten days, 25 years ago. It was intended to do small scripting things, but has since been co-opted to produce entire applications. Compare that time frame with the design of Clojure, which Rich Hickey spent 18 months on.

#### Returning `null`

This is pretty similar to `NaN` because JavaScript still allows using `null` in calculations, e.g. `null + 1 === 1`. So this still lead to bugs, perhaps even more dangerous ones because you end up with an actual number as opposed to `NaN`.

However, one benefit of using `null` over `NaN` is that TypeScript will prevent you from using `null` in calculations. This isn't the case with `NaN` because `NaN` is considered a `number`.

#### Throwing an error

This is the safest way to handle an invalid value because it prevents the caller from accidentally using the invalid value in further calculations.

The downside to this is that a try-catch is required for each invocation.

#### Conclusion

In JavaScript: Throw an error

In TypeScript: Return `null`

Comment: The reason JS uses `NaN` is because its "number" type is an IEEE floating point value, so it already has operations with that result, as well as `Inf` and `-Inf`. If it had a separate integer type, `parseInt` would probably be defined differently.

Comment: @IMSoP That explains why `NaN` exists, but not why it's the return value of `parseInt`. I guess they might have just thought "Hey, we have a value called `NaN`, so we might as well return it when we can't return an actual number". But I guess what you mean is that if there would be an integer type, then `NaN` wouldn't be an option.

Comment: Considering that "NaN" is short for "Not a Number" it is quite reasonable to return it if you can't return a number :-) The huge advantage of NaN is that you it propagates through all kinds of calculations, so you can do all kinds of maths and check if the final result is NaN. For example adding three numbers parsed with parseInt will give NaN if parsing any of them fails.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yeah it makes sense to return it. I guess what doesn't make sense is that `NaN` actually **is** a number (`typeof NaN === 'number'`), so propagation can be unexpected

Comment: It's because JS was designed to add 20 - 200 lines of interactivity to webpages. Sadly if you give some people a spade first they will refuse to use an excavator because "the spade is easier". It's on of the paradoxes in programming that can make it very challenging. The entire JS ecosystem today is basically just the blind leading the blind imo.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby there are two functions I typically use to parse an integer: `to_i` and `Integer()` (there very well may be others).

- `to_i` returns `0` given a non-integer input.
- `Integer()` throws an error given a non-integer input.

I regularly use them both depending on what would be the most useful result in the caller.

I imagine if you only had an integer parser that threw an exception someone would eventually find that they're constantly catching and ignoring that exception and abstract that behavior to a function that returns `null`.

If you only had an integer parser that returned `null` I bet someone would eventually find that they're throwing exceptions a lot when they get a `null` return value and abstract that behavior.

> Is there a significant benefit to one of the solutions below?

I think it will always depend on what you need to happen next in your caller.

Since `NaN` and `null` are both falsey I imagine for the most part which you return wouldn't really matter. But if `NaN` was significantly different from `null` to multiple parts of your code, you might end up needing a version that returns `NaN`.

Answer (score -1):

In case of such function there should be at least one `tryXXX` which would return `bool` and and actual result (if any). There could be also added function `XXX` which simply calls `tryXXX` and in case of getting `false` it would throw an exception.

Comment: This Try-Parse pattern is common in .NET, but how would you implement this in JavaScript with the lack of an `out` parameter?

Comment: For example `return [ok, i];` or `return { ok: ok, value: i };`, or a very stupid way: `function tryParse(str, ret) { ret[0] = i; return success; }; const iContainer = []; const success = tryParse("hello", iContainer); if (success) { const i = iContainer[0]; }`

Comment: @DuncanLuk, granted in .Net is very clean pattern, but in JS like Jörg wrote. The point here is to avoid throwing an exception if you don't have to, yet you provide meaningful API. Throwing exception is very costly, thus it is better to have a pair of those functions.